# Using sjPlot in R to carry out wilcoxon-mann whitney on a factor variable

Tags: r, sjplot

I have two variables I want to compare: one containing a variable on age (continuous) and one containing a variable on stroke status (did or did not have stroke, factor).  I can do this happily using

```
wilcox.test (allcoding$age~allcoding$stroketia)
```

However, I struggle with doing this in `sjPlot` as it wants both to be numeric

```
sjt.mwu(mwu(allcoding$age, allcoding$stroketia))
Performing Mann-Whitney-U-Test...
---------------------------------
showing statistics between groups (x|y)
Error in wilcox.test.default(xsub, ysub.n, paired = TRUE) :
 'y' must be numeric
```

How do I do the equivalent of the `"~"` in sjPlot rather than `","`?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you provide sample data in your post? Also, `sjt.mwu` is to produce HTML output, I reckon that the problem is with the `mwu`; The `mwu` takes two numeric vectors. Leaving the data on side, the second question in your post is not clear to me at all. The `mwu` takes arguments `mwu(x = your numbers, grp = your groups, ...)`, the `~` is used in formula objects but why and where would you like to include it?

Comment: Hi Konrad, thanks for your help.  Its a difficult thing to give example data for unfortunately, because its esentially a xtab I want to do.  Ive already done it for previous data, e.g.

`sjt.xtab (allcoding$smoking, allcoding$stroketia, variableLabels = c("Smoking", "Stroke Status"), showColPerc = TRUE, tdcol.col = "black")`

Ive used this to produce a chi-sq test as both variables are factors.  Now instead, I want to essentially do the same thing but produce a xtab containing mean and standard deviation and the result of wilcoxon because one value is a factor and the other is continuous

Comment: Then it would be difficult to help you. Could you just post the output from running the `mwu` without the `sjt.mwu`? It would be necessary to have a look at your variables, possibly you may be able to address the problem with use of `as.numeric` but it's not possible to say without having a look at the data. *Edit:* and all of those variables are numeric vectors?

Comment: Using mwu I get

`mwu(allcoding$age, allcoding$stroketia)`
`Performing Mann-Whitney-U-Test...`
`---------------------------------`
`showing statistics between groups (x|y)`
`Error in wilcox.test.default(xsub, ysub.n, paired = TRUE) : `
 ` 'y' must be numeric`

There are not all numeric no, one is numeric and the other is a factor.  I can for example do wilcox.test, which gives me the desiered result, but I cant table it

Comment: I basically want a table that looks like http://imgur.com/WDs6zjs

Comment: Simple stuff to achieve, try with your grouping variables as *1, 0* for the groups.

Comment: What does `str(allcoding$stroketia)` print? I suggest converting that vector into numeric.

Comment: It's a bit strange because the grouping variable is automatically coerced to numeric if it's a factor.

Answer (score 0):

I can only reproduce this error when the grouping variable is of type `character`.

```
library(sjmisc)
library(sjPlot)
a <- runif(50, 10, 30)
b <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 50, replace = T)
# throws an error
mwu(a, b)
```

However, when you coerce to factor, it works:

```
mwu(a, as.factor(b))
sjt.mwu(mwu(a, as.factor(b)))
```

Could you try this?